# Update ng-model value by ng-click function will give a console error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was using angularjs 1.6 and the browser console keep give the **Error: [$parse:syntax]** when I enter the page.

and some message like this.

```
<span class="switch" ng-click="disableValue() undefined ? optionValue: optionValue=!optionValue" ng-class="{ checked:optionValue, disabled:undefined }" style="margin-top:0px;" ng-model="optionValue">
```

The default value is true when I enter the page and I can set it off by click the switch button.

Functionality is work fine. but this error is always prompt in console and I don't know why.

In html

```js
angular.module('app').controller({
  $scope.optionValue = true;
  
  $scope.disableValue = function()
  {
    $scope.optionValue = !$scope.optionValue;
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<switch style="margin-top:0px;" ng-model="optionValue" ng-click="disableValue()"></switch>
```

Can somebody give a hint? I guess the issues in on  ng-model and ng-click.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply modify your variable directly in `ng-click`.

***Example:***

Try to click on `Hello, World!` statement.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.colorVal= true;
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp">
  <span ng-class="{red: colorVal}" ng-click="colorVal = !colorVal">
  Hello, World! </span>
</div>
```

***Remember:***
Use [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) with `input`, `select` & `textarea`.

Comment: But if I want to show a switch button and it the option may be on or off depend on different situation which will decide by backend, Souldn't I use ng-model here?

Comment: Also no need for `ng-model`. It's the same concept, you can handle it in the same way.